# Setting up a object literal array to pass values to a server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am passing a large number of variables to a http server.  Instead of writing a long command prompt, I want to set up the variables as a object literal.  If I set it up statically it works fine.  But I want to populate the object in a loop.
This works:

```
var data= { T1: 123,
              R1: 'L',
              T2: 3434,
              R2: 'R'};

$.post(url,data, get_outcome);
```

But I want to write a loop that does this, and I need to understand how I would populate the object literal with my variable names and values. (the example is just to demonstrate) If I try it this way it fails:

```
var data=[];
data.push({T1: 123});
data.push({T2: 3434});
data.push({R1: 'L'});
data.push({R2: 'R'});

$.post(url,data, get_outcome);
```

I have even tried this:

```
var data=[];

 var a,val,name;
     name={"T1","T2","R1","R2"};
     val={"123","3434","L","R"};
 for(a=0;a<4;a++){   
   data.push({name[a]:val[a]});
 }
 $.post(url,data,get_outcome);
```

The final function should work like this:

```
function Save(var values, var val){
 var a,name;
 var data=[];
  for(a=0;a<values;a++){
      name="T"+(a+1);
      data.push({name: val[a]});
      } 
   $.post(url,data,get_outcome);
  }
```

What am I doing wrong ?

I implemented the solution suggested by Rajiv as follows:

```
function save(){
  var data=[];

  function dataPush(name, val) {
         var obj = {};
         obj[name] = val;
         data.push(obj);
     }
           //eg hardcoded values 
        dataPush('T1',123);
        dataPush('T2',3123);
        dataPush('R1',"R");
        dataPush('R2',"L");  
           // values stored in arrays elsewhere
    for(a=2;a<max;a++){
        temp="T"+(a+1);
        dataPush(temp,T[a]);
        temp="R"+(a+1);
        dataPush(temp,R[a]);
    }


    $.post(url,data, get_outcome);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       var arry = [];
       function dataPush(name, val) {
            var obj = {};
            obj[name] = val;
            arry.push(obj);
        }

        KeyName =["T1","T2","R1","R2"];
        KeyVal = ["123", "3434", "L", "R"];
        for (var i = 0; i < KeyName.length; i++) {
                dataPush(KeyName[i], KeyVal[i]);
        }
        console.log(arry);
```

After that used this array

Comment: I am used to the Java programming forums and waiting for days to get any responses. I must say, you Javascript guys are super-helpfull. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating an array. Create like this

```
var data={};
data.T1 = 123;
data.T2 = 3434;
data.R1 = 'L';
data.R2 = 'R';
$.post(url,data,get_outcome);
```

And When using the array

```
var data={};
var a,val,name;
name={"T1","T2","R1","R2"};
val={"123","3434","L","R"};
for(a=0;a<4;a++){   
   data[name[a]] = val[a];
}
```

Comment: Please show me how I use push to add entries to data.

Comment: @Jan, `push()` is used with array to create a simple object literal you don't need push

Comment: I would like to know how to use it though - because as my example shows that's the way I am trying to do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = {};

var name = ["T1", "T2", "R1", "R2"];
var val = [123, 3434, "L", "R"];

name.forEach(function(el, index){
   data[el] = val[i];
});
```

Will produce

```
 var data= {  T1: 123,
              R1: 'L',
              T2: 3434,
              R2: 'R'
           };
```

Comment: The solution assumes that the variable names are available. I will edit original question.

Comment: Tell me how you are getting T1, R1?

Comment: T1 is simply the name of the variable that the server wants. The example function (bottom) shows my attempt at setting that up.

Comment: If you can use push to add data - I think that would clarify everything.

Comment: You can not push into an object. You need to assign a value to the appropriate key.

Comment: Please have a look at my attempt using Rajiv's suggestion.  I think I am doing what you suggest but its still not working right.

Comment: I am trying to use your example - but please explain what index is  and where it came from ?

Answer (score 1):

All I understood from your question is that you need to create a object and send that to server. The object needs to have some properties that you wanna add dynamically, rather than statically.

If that's it, you can do so as :

```
var localData = [{key1: 'val1'},{key2: 'val2'},{key3: 'val3'}, {key4: 'val4', key5:'val5'}] // your data that you want to send 

function createPayload(localData) {
 var payload = {}; 
 localData.forEach(function(o) {
  for(var key in o) {
    payload[key] = o[key]; 
  }
 });
 return payload;
}

var objectToSend = createPayload(localData); 
console.log(objectToSend);
```